# Weird closure behavior in python

Tags: python, closures

I have a following simple code:

```
def get():
    return [lambda: i for i in [1, 2, 3]]

for f in get():
    print(f())
```

As expected from my python knowledge, output is 3 - entire list will contain last value of `i`. But how this works internally?

AFAIK, python variables are simply reference to objects, so first closure must enclose object first `i` reference - and this object is definitely 1, not 3 O_O. How it happens that python closure encloses variable itself instead of object this variable reference? Does it save variable name as plain text, some "reference to variable" or what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closures don't refer to *variables* but rather to *scopes*. Since the last value of `i` in its scope is '3', all three closures return the same. To "lock" the current value of a variable, create a new scope just for it:

```
def get() : return [ (lambda x: lambda: x)(i) for i in [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
for f in get() : print( f() )
```

Comment: Is it some additional information available on the subject so i can see what hidden variables are used to "save" scope, access it, etc?

Comment: `(lambda x: lambda : x)(i)` is one of the ugliest things I've seen done in Python. Ick. (Not that your answer is wrong or bad, per-se, just saying - it's hard to read).

Comment: @EyeofHell: I think [pep-227](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) is the canonical document about python scoping rules. Also, there are some good answers on this here on SO, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: @Lattyware: de gustibus non est disputandum.

Comment: @thg435 This is exactly why I added my little disclaimer ;).

Comment: @Lattyware, it's hard to read because Python was never designed from the bottom-up to elegantly support these sorts of functional-style constructs. The equivalent code in a language like, e.g., Scheme would be both more idiomatic and more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @GregE. I don't think it's impossible to do nicely in Python. I think jdi's answer of `functools.partial()` and `lambda` mixed is the nicest solution, it describes what is being done in a nicer way - from my point of view.

Comment: @Lattyware, it certainly is nicer, and I'm not saying that it's impossible to do in a reasonably clear manner. Nevertheless, the fact that it requires importing a library and isn't cleanly achievable using core language constructs suggests that it's never been a major design priority. I like Python a lot, but it's always been dismissive of, if not actively hostile toward, language features that are integral to functional style programming.

Comment: @EyeofHell: BTW I might be not completely correct about how this works. I posted a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110304/auto-bind-scope-variables-in-a-closure) in hope that someone comes up with a better explanation.

Answer (score 14):

As @thg435 points out, a lambda will not encapsulate the values at that moment, but rather the scope. There are too small ways you can address this:

lambda default argument "hack"

```
[ lambda v=i: v for i in [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

Or use functools.partial

```
from functools import partial
[ partial(lambda v: v, i) for i in [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

Essentially you have to move the scope to be local to the function you are creating. Generally I like using `partial` more often since you can pass it a callable, and any args and kargs to create a callable with a proper closure. Internally, it is wrapping your original callable so the scope is shifted for you.

Comment: +1 For using partial here, I think it's a much cleaner approach. You might want to edit your code though, spaces inside list brackets are bad according to PEP-8. (I know you were following the asker, I edited it there).

Comment: @Lattyware: Thanks! lambdas are cool but I always find them more messy to read. partial just feels so much more readable and portable.

Comment: 100% agree, I try to avoid lambdas wherever I can, and this is a prime case where partial is both more clear and simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Each `lambda` is actually referring to the same `i`, which is a variable created by the list comprehension. Upon termination of the list comprehension, `i` maintains the value of the final element that it was assigned to until it goes out of scope (which is prevented by encapsulating it within a function and returning it, namely the `lambda`). As others have pointed out, closures don't maintain copies of values, but rather maintain references to variables that were defined within their scope.