# Connect signal to function with many argument?

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

I have this function in python def:

```
def niveau(controlName,idNiveau)
```

I want to connect it to this signal in this way:

```
QObject.connect(dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, 'buttonBox'), SIGNAL('accepted()'),niveau(control,1))
```

I got the following error:

> Qt signal not callable

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because `QObject.connect` with 3 parameters means:

> `QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection)`

The third parameter you're passing isn't a callable, but the return value of the call to `niveau(control,1)`.

The arguments a signal is emitted with is determined at emit time, not at connect time. If you would like to speicfy some (or all) parameters at connect time, you can:

- use `functools.partial`:

  ```
  from functools import partial
  QObject.connect(... , partial(niveau, control, 1))
  ```
- use a lambda

  ```
  QObject.connect(... , lambda ctrl=control, id=1: niveau(ctrl, id))
  ```

edit:

By the way, you should really use [new style signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) - old style signals [will not be supported anymore in PyQt5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#old-style-signals-and-slots).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i use my function (niveau) many time and with differents parameter :
QObject.connect(button1... , lambda: niveau(control, 1))
QObject.connect(button2... , lambda: niveau(control, 2))
QObject.connect(button3... , lambda: niveau(control, 3))
so in the result he use onely the last parameter 3 for this case ???

Comment: You're probably creating your connections in a loop - the problem is that the scope of the lamdbdas is the local scope they are created within. So if a variable changes, it also changes within the lambda, so you'll always see the last value `3`. It's the same behaviour described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109838/weird-closure-behavior-in-python). That's why `partial` is preferable here (and I listed it first), it doesn't have this problem. I'll update my answer to account for this.